# CFOUTPUT Query variable name doesn't work on CF11 Linux

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to reference a query from a struct and use it in other cfm files but I get this error message from CF11 Linux:"Attribute validation error for tag cfoutput. The value of the attribute query, which is currently Application.SRS.RequestTypes, is invalid.'

It works on CF9 window server.

Here are the code:

entry.cfm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTypeDesc( request_type ) {
      <CFOutput Query="Application.SRS.RequestTypes">
        if ( request_type == "#request_type_code#" ) {
          document.getElementById( "TypeDesc" ).innerHTML = "#JSStringFormat( request_type_desc )#";
        }
      </CFOutput>
      if ( request_type == "A" ) {
        document.getElementById( "Developer_Label" ).className = "req";
        this.form.Developer.value = '#UCase( Request.LogonID )#';
        this.form.Developer.onblur();
      } else {
        document.getElementById( "Developer_Label" ).className = "";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

load-type.cfm: query statement

```
<CFQuery Name="RequestTypes" DataSource="#Application.SRS.AppDataSource#" BlockFactor="100">
    SELECT 
    FROM srs_type
    ORDER BY request_type_code
</CFQuery>
<CFLock Timeout="60" ThrowOnTimeout="Yes" Type="EXCLUSIVE"  Scope="APPLICATION">
    <CFSET Application.SRS.RequestTypes = RequestTypes>
    <CFModule Template="#Application.ModuleDir#/query-to-struct.cfm"
        DataQuery="#RequestTypes#"
        KeyFieldList="request_type_code"
        VariableName="Application.SRS.RequestTypesStruct">
</CFLock>
```

query-to-struct.cfm:

```
<CFParam Name="Attributes.DataQuery" Type="query">
<CFParam Name="Attributes.KeyFieldList" Type="string">
<CFParam Name="Attributes.VariableName" Type="string">

<CFSET ResultStruct = StructNew()>
<CFOutput Query="Attributes.DataQuery">
    <CFSET KeyString = "">
    <CFLoop List="#Attributes.KeyFieldList#" Index="field">
        <CFSET KeyString = ListAppend( KeyString, Evaluate( field ) )>
    </CFLoop>
    <CFSET ResultStruct[KeyString] = StructNew()>
    <CFLoop List="#Attributes.DataQuery.ColumnList#" Index="col">
        <CFSET ResultStruct[KeyString][col] = Evaluate( col )>
    </CFLoop>
</CFOutput>

<CFIF Attributes.VariableName contains ".">
    <CFSET "#Attributes.VariableName#" = ResultStruct>
<CFELSE>
    <CFSET "Caller.#Attributes.VariableName#" = ResultStruct>
</CFIF>
```

Comment: on your CF10 server, cfdump Application.SRS.RequestTypes and see if it is defined at all.  If it isn't, then try to debug your code and see why `load-type.cfm` is not being called.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is even related to the code you're showing to us? It's about "SRS.SeverityCodes". I can only find a reference to "SBS.RequestType" in your code

Comment: I updated the error message, it should be "Application.SRS.RequstTypes".

Comment: The solution I could figure out now is adding <cfinclude template="#Application.SRS.ModuleDir#/load-types.cfm"> to my first file(entry.cfm).  It doesn't need to add <cfclude...> on CF9 window server.

Comment: You may read this http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/24/moving-coldfusion-applications-from-windows-to-linux